# Get url for action in controller with attribute routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, attributerouting

I have action in controller with ASP.NET MVC 5 attribute routing.

```
[RoutePrefix("ControllerName")]
public class MyController : Controller
{
    [Route("ActionName")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

When I try to get url in action like this (Controller.Url)

```
Url.Action("Index", "My")
```

I get

> /My/Index

When I do the same in View (It's WebViewPage.Url),

```
@Url.Action("Index", "My")
```

I get

> /ControllerName/ActionName

How can I get /ControllerName/ActionName in action?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to construct the url from other controllers, you need to make use of the UrlHelper class like this:

```
var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(ControllerContext.RequestContext);
var url = urlHelper.Action("Index", "My");
```

This would construct your desired result: /ControllerName/ActionName

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Url.Action("Index", "My")
```

You need to use only part before *Controller* as a your controller name. Do the same for `@Url.Action` in views.

Comment: Good point - minor bug when creating an example. I have corrected it. Still looking for answers to the question. :)